# Powershell update Fax field from existing TelephoneNumber field

Tags: powershell, active-directory

My organization is such that the phone numbers and fax number have the same last three characters, eg:

```
...

- phone: 012345 - 111
- fax:   015432 - 111

- phone: 012345 - 112
- fax:   015432 - 112

- phone: 012345 - 113
- fax:   015432 - 113

...
```

The user information contains only the phone numbers and I want to fill the fax fields calculating the number from the phone number field.

This is what I have so far, but I can't get the last part that is supposed to pill up the fax field.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'telephonenumber -Like "*"' -Properties telephonenumber |
    Select-Object @{'Name'='3digits';'Expression'={-Join $_.telephonenumber[-3..-1]}} |
    % {Set-ADUser $_ -fax ('+12 (34) 567 ' + $_.3digits)}
```